# How to update fixture column in Rails Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, testing, minitest, fixtures

How can i update column of a fixture for temporary use only with update_column command. 
Right now i  have following command that is running fine:

```
name = names(:one)
    role = roles(:one)
    name.role_id = role.id
    assert name.save
```

**And it is running fine, but is there any efficient way to do it in one line something like name.update_column(---, ----) ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks @richfisher for your answer, later on i figure out another way to do it.  **`update_attributes`** is not  a good idea to be used in test, because the problem with **update_attributes** is

- `It runs callbacks and validations`
  and usually we do not want to run these things in test cases

Instead of update_attributes we can use **update_column** like this

```
name.update_column(:role_id, roles(:one).id)
```

The **advantage** of using **update_column** is

- `It did not run callbacks and validations`

Comment: The **disadvantage** (sometimes) is also that it does not run callbacks or updates.  

It's possible to use update_column to save an invalid record, and there are cases where that can result in bogus test results.

Answer (score 5):

```
name = names(:one)
name.update_attributes(role_id: roles(:one).id)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed without.